# Showing results for Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

Firefox is showing this error:

> Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amountv

when I execute this code:

```
   function myDraw(x1,y1){      
        var img1 = document.createElement('img');
        img1.src='i12.png'; 
        img1.onload = function (){
        var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx=c.getContext('2d');     
        ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0,y1,x1,5,5,y1,x1);
        }       
        var sizeArrey =[1,13,25,37,49,61,73,85,97,109, 125,140];
        for (var i = 0; i < sizeArrey.length; i++ ){            
        y1 = sizeArrey[i];}
        x1 += 2;              
        var loopTimer = setTimeout('myDraw('+x1+','+y1+')', 7);
}
function myDraw1(x11, y11){
    var img=document.createElement('img');
    img.src='logo11.png'; 
        img.onload = function (){
            var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx=c.getContext('2d');     
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,x11,50,125,55,x11,50); 
            }   
     x11 += 1;  
     var loopTimer = setTimeout('myDraw1('+x11+','+y11+')', 3 );        
}
myDraw(0,0)
setTimeout("myDraw1(0,0)",1400);
```

Help me please, what is wrong here?

Comment: You are calling and incrementing x11 333 times a second, forever...And because you are sending a string it is incrementin from '1' to '11' to '111' to '1111'...

Comment: how can I limit the incrementing saving the animation effect? I tried
 ` while (x11 !=== 149) {x11 += 1};` and lost animation efect like I put 0 mls

Comment: sory found ) used `clearTimeout(loopTimer );`
Thank you very much!!